# d-max heap insert items from the top and down

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to implement an insert function in c++ to build a d-max heap. The d is referring to the number of children in the heap and a max heap is a heap which has its' elements structured in a priority (3,2,1...). The heap is supposed to be represented as an array and the function I'm looking for is adding items from the top one by one and then continuing downward. This may seem like an easy task but I'm confused about how this is going to work.

Here is a rough example of the template function:

```
template <typename Comparable>
void buildHeapTopDown(Comparable arr[], int size, int d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        arr[0] = 2;
        arr[1] = 3;
        arr[2] = 4;
        arr[3] = 6;
        arr[4] = 9;
    }
}
```

Now as this is some really basic code the function is not really informative about the way a d-heap works. What I mean is I have not implemented the theory behind the d-heap, which basically is pretty much the same as the theory behind a binary heap (we only replace 2 with d in the formulas). The formulas for finding a parent and a child for a heap then becomes: 
`(x-1) / d`, `x*d + 1` (left child) and `x*d + 2` (right child).

I also know there is a way to create a heap using the `<algorithm>` class, but as these functions are already prepared and they are using vectors, it's not really what I'm looking for.

Example using the algorithm class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myInts[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 10, 13, 15, 6, 8, 17, 9, 11, 9 };
    vector <int> v(myInts, myInts + 15);

    make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "Initial max heap: " << v.front() << endl;

    pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.pop_back();
    cout << "Max heap after pop: " << v.front() << endl;

    v.push_back(77); // insert example 
    push_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "Max heap after push: " << v.front() << endl;

    sort_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

    cout << "Final sorted range:";

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << " " << v[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    getchar();
    getchar();

}
```

Anyone who can give any hints how to do it as the way I described in the top?

Comment: The functions in `<algorithm>` are not restricted to vectors, they work on anything that provides an appropriate iterator interface (in case of heap functions anything with random access iterators). Note that pointers are an iterator interface for built-in arrays; the iterator interface is explicitly designed that way. Pointers are random access iterators, and therefore suitable iterators for the heap functions.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I just always assumed that because of the code I have seen related to the class. Thanks for sharing!